How to implement frequencies (drive,measuring) and temperature in a qiskit Noise Model?
Im trying to build a qiskit Noise Model but the NoiseModel() class does not admit temperature, frequencies or measuring time.
I thought about using the pulse library from qiskit but Im not very sure how to do it. Any thoughts?
